# Draw border when the Control is focused

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to draw a border on any Control that has focus, the border has to disappear when the control no longer has focus. I have tried to below code to draw a border, but I have no idea how I can let the border be painted before it disappears.

```
void mButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ((Control)sender).ClientRectangle, Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

Comment: Do you want the border to be inside the control or outside? Are there any controls inside containers? Some controls doesn't even get focus. Your question it too vague. Be more specific.

Comment: prefix the paint code with `if ( (Control)sender == ActiveControl)..` Paint is triggered by the system, at least for buttons and other controls that change appearance upon focus changed anyway. For others you will need to watch the leave/enter events.

Comment: I've edited my answer, tiny optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. (Turned out to be a lot messier than I expected.)

```
   public partial class FormSO29381768 : Form
   {
      // Constructor
      public FormSO29381768()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         InstallEventHandlers(this);
      }


      /// <summary>
      /// Recursive method to install the paint event handler for all container controls on a form, 
      /// including the form itself, and also to install the "enter" event handler for all controls 
      /// on a form.
      /// </summary>
      private void InstallEventHandlers(Control containerControl)
      {
         containerControl.Paint -= Control_Paint;  // Defensive programming
         containerControl.Paint += Control_Paint;

         foreach (Control nestedControl in containerControl.Controls)
         {
            nestedControl.Enter -= Control_ReceivedFocus;  // Defensive programming
            nestedControl.Enter += Control_ReceivedFocus;

            if (nestedControl is ScrollableControl)
               InstallEventHandlers(nestedControl);
         }
      }


      /// <summary>
      /// Event handler method that gets called when a control receives focus. This just indicates 
      /// that the whole form needs to be redrawn. (This is a bit inefficient, but will presumably 
      /// only be noticeable if there are many, many controls on the form.)
      /// </summary>
      private void Control_ReceivedFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         this.Refresh();
      }


      /// <summary>
      /// Event handler method to draw a dark blue rectangle around a control if it has focus, and 
      /// if it is in the container control that is invoking this method.
      /// </summary>
      private void Control_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
      {
         Control activeControl = this.ActiveControl;
         if (activeControl != null && activeControl.Parent == sender) 
         {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkBlue, 
                        new Rectangle(activeControl.Location.X - 2, activeControl.Location.Y - 2, 
                                      activeControl.Size.Width + 4, activeControl.Size.Height + 4));
         }
      }
   }
```